# Polynomial approximation of max function

Tags: functions, polynomials, approximation, maximum

Let me just say upfront I'm not a mathematician, I'm rather looking for a practical answer to my question. I was wondering if there is a polynomial approximation for the function

$$\max(0,x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} x, x>0\\0, x \leq 0\end{array}
              \right.$$
I was thinking something like the sigmoid function could be useful and since it can be tweaked to output values in the range $[0,1)$, then the answer to my question would be the product $x * sigmoid(x)$, correct? If so, in order to increase accuracy, I would need a sigmoid function with steeper slope around 0, so something like $\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}$ for some $k\geq1$. The sigmoid function has then a well-known Taylor series approximation which I could compute in Mathematica.

Comment: Not polynomial approximations but try: `Plot[Ramp[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick]` and `Plot[x UnitStep[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick]`.

Comment: @Syed the problem with this is that if `f[x_] := x Ramp[x]` then `f[1]` equals to `1` and not `x`.

Comment: Should it be called something other than `x` , if it is a constant after x>0? @bmf

Comment: @Syed yes, of course. stupid me....blushing :/

Comment: `Plot[x LogisticSigmoid[x], {x, -10, 10}]`

Comment: @Syed how does that help answer my question?

Comment: Your question is phrased as @bmf interpreted it. You have shown a ramp in the $\LaTeX$ equation but want a steeper slope near the origin.

Comment: On top of what @Syed mentioned, if you think what a polynomial in one variable is, you easily conclude that you are asking is impossible. And also, you mentioned a polynomial approximation, but the discussion has nothing to do with polynomial constructions. What Syed suggested as advice is a well-defined alternative

Comment: @Jimakos You suggestion looks reasonable, why are you not happy with it?

Comment: I wonder how you are going to use this polynomial. (It's end-use would affect what form you want the approximation in, in my imagination.) The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem says there is an approximation within any tolerance you wish to specify, although the degree may be really large.  Chebyshev approximation (like Flinty's answer) usually gives a good approximation to the best approximation possible of a given degree. There are efficient ways to compute and evaluate high-degree polynomial approximations without expressing the approximation explicitly in polynomial form.

Comment: Your function is already piecewise polynomial, why do you need a polynomial? If it is to get something smooth then you could use `Sqrt[1/a+x^2]+x` to approximate it, where larger a increase the fit but makes the derivatives more extreme

Answer (score 6):

`Limit[x LogisticSigmoid[k x], k -> Infinity]` gives `ConditionalExpression[x, x > 0]` so give a large `k` and you'll get something close to your `Max` / `Ramp` function. Unfortunately a Taylor `Series` will have poor convergence.

You could use Chebyshev polynomials like this (where I'm using 10 terms, although you can increase this):

```
f[x_] := Ramp[x]
basis = Array[ChebyshevT[#, x] &, 10, 0];
expansion = 2/Pi Integrate[f[x] #/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}] & /@ basis;
approx = -expansion[[1]]/2 + expansion . basis;
Plot[{f[x], approx}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: chebyshev expansion]

`HornerForm[approx]` gives a fairly compact expression:
$$x \left(x \left(\left(x^2 \left(\frac{448}{45 \pi }-\frac{256 x^2}{63 \pi }\right)-\frac{80}{9 \pi
   }\right) x^2+\frac{40}{9 \pi }\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{9 \pi }$$

Unfortunately, Chebyshev polynomials are only good approximations on the interval [-1, +1].

Comment: `Rescale` (or algebra I) can be used to map an interval $[a,b]$ back and forth between $[-1,1]$. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @flint's answer, one can "play dumb" and do something like this, finding the least squares difference fit over a range:

```
With[{f = Ramp, range = {-5, 5}, n = 10},
  With[{params = Array[c, n]},
   With[{eqn = FromDigits[params, x]},
    eqn /. Last@Minimize[
       Integrate[(f[x] - eqn)^2,
        Prepend[range, x]], params]]]] // Together
```

$$\frac{-21879 x^8+1261260 x^6-26276250 x^4+303187500 x^2+512000000
   x+172265625}{1024000000}$$

```
Plot[{Ramp[x], %}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's my way to play dumb: Chebyshev interpolation. It's almost equivalent to @flinty's result, but in a different form. (The two approach each other as the degree increases.)

```
{a, b} = {-1, 2};  (* Pick interval *)
deg = 10;          (* Pick degree *)
xx =               (* Chebyshev nodes *)
  Rescale[Sin[Pi/2 Range[-1. deg, deg, 2]/deg], {-1, 1}, {a, b}];
yy = Max[0, #] & /@ xx; (* y = f(x) *)

(* Barycentric is particularly appropriate and efficient here *)
approx = Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation[
   xx, yy,
   "Weights" -> (* optional: increases accuracy slightly *)
    ReplacePart[
     Table[(-1)^k, {k, 0, Length@xx - 1}], {1 -> 1/2, -1 -> 1/2}]];

Plot[{Max[0, x], approx[x]}, {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

You can evaluate the derivative (first derivative only) by passing a `1` as a second argument:

```
Plot[approx[x, 1], {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: My "play dumb" argument was that if you don't know basis functions or other useful facts you can always use brute force with `Integrate` and `Minimize` and hope for the best! ;)

Comment: @kirma I just meant use it [my code] as a black box. :)